# HMS Health Record Sleep API returning empty HealthRecords array

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

I am calling this API https://health-api.cloud.huawei.com/healthkit/v1/healthRecords?startTime=1633700548000000000&endTime=1636378903389000000&dataType=com.huawei.health.record.sleep&subDataType=com.huawei.continuous.sleep.fragment.

**NOTE:**

The startTime and endTime is in nanoseconds.

**ISSUE:**
I have plenty of sleep data but the API is just **returning an empty health Records array**. Please tell me what the problem is. And where can I get the steps from. There are no steps in health record section.

Answer (score 1):

```
QUESTION 1 - “I have plenty of sleep data but the API is just returning an empty health Records array"

SOLUTION:

Please refer the below link for “Querying Health Records in a Specified Period”

https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-References/get-health-record-by-datatype-0000001142843917#section9701181322219

 

Use the valid parameters like starttime, endtime in above API and apply the required “Health Record Data Types”. The public data types are listed in the below link.

https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/public-dt-0000001050069714#section147711038114919

There are different types like continuous, instantaneous, total, delta or statistics, you can pick as per your requirement referring to above link

 

Possible datatypes you asked (not exact) - 

steps, - com.huawei.continuous.steps.total
sleep, - com.huawei.continuous.sleep.fragment
heart rate - com.huawei.instantaneous.heart_rate
calories data - com.huawei.continuous.calories.burnt

QUESTION 2 - “Authorization Url issue”

SOLUTION :
It is due to the network restrictions in your work location

Please check you network restrictions. Please removing the proxy and try it in open network.
```